# Is it possible to record video on an iPhone 13 mini and have sound coming from an external audio interface?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, video

I would like to record videos of myself playing musical instruments and have the sound being fed via my USB-C audio interface (MOTU Ultralite MK5).

I have tried the answer given in [another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229346/how-do-i-record-video-on-ios-with-external-audio-interface/247496#247496) but this doesn't work on an iPhone 13 mini.

I first connect a Lightning to USB-C cable to my iPhone, open the camera app, choose to record video, then plug the USB-C end to the MOTU UL 5, and finally click record. I then play a few notes on my digital piano which is plugged into the MOTU UL5 and can see levels on the MOTU UL-5 meter.

However, on review of the recorded video there is no sound.

[How do I record video on iOS with external audio interface?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229346/how-do-i-record-video-on-ios-with-external-audio-interface/247496#247496)

Comment: Nice work linking to an existing question. Are you going to make us guess what specifically isn’t working?

Comment: @bmike Noted. I've edited the question. Newbie. Learning. Appreciate the encouragement.

Comment: Awesome. Are you using the camera connector to get the  most functional USB connection? Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter

https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MK0W2AM/A my guess is the charge cable is not what you need despite it “fitting” in the socket.

Comment: Okay. I was just using a Lightning to USB-C cable. USB Camera Adapter arriving in three days. I will report after testing.

Comment: I have tested it with an official Apple Lightning to USB 3 Camera adapter. It works. As per the linked post, the Camera Adapter must be connected first. Then open the camera app and select to record video. Then connect the Camera Adapter to the audio interface (in my case a MOTU UL MK 5). It will only receive from channels 1 and 2.

Comment: In light of this, should I delete this question? Or edit the title to reflect my specific audio interface?

Comment: No, answer what you learned and how you decided to go. It will surely help others. So much good information here in the comments